# Compaq 9009 in linux

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-10.04

Do you know how can I activate this keyboard in linux to use its shortcuts ?

Comment: is this the keyboard: http://www.pcplan-it.com/hp_blksilver.jpg ?

Comment: Yeah, That's it. But in linux listing I can't find this model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred method [KeyTouch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyTouch). You need the [keytouch](http://packages.ubuntu.com/keytouch) [image: Install keytouch] package, as well as [keytouch-editor](http://packages.ubuntu.com/keytouch-editor) [image: Install keytouch-editor] if your keyboard model is not supported out-of-the-box.

Occasionally KeyTouch may not cope. Then [Hotkeys/Troubleshooting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting) and [Hotkeys/Architecture](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Architecture) explain how to do it the hard way.